# Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when running a lambda function trying to query data from rds

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function querying all rows from table `accounts`

```
const pool = require("../db");
'use strict';

function getAllUsers (event, context, callback) {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  try {
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM accounts;').then((r) => {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(r.rows)
      })
    }).catch((e) => callback(null, {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: e.toString()
    }))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
};
```

serverless.yaml file:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline

service: node-serverless
app: server-app


provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 5




functions:
          
  getAllUsers:
    handler: handler.getAllUsers
    events:
      - http:
          path: /users
          method: get
          cors: true
```

But I am running into an error:

```
GET /dev/users (λ: getAllUsers)
✖ Unhandled exception in handler 'getAllUsers'.
✖ Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

(502 error)

same error when deployed and running offline...
I am using node-pg to pool from my db.

Comment: Any solution? I'm facing same error.